# Is there any shorter way to write this method?

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python that should look like this for example:

```
line = ['0', '1', '0', 'R', '1']
```

I wrote this function, but can this be done in the easier way?

```
def checkCardCommands(line):
    if line[0] == '0' or line[0] == '1':
        if line[1] == '0' or line[1] == '1' or line[1] == 'None':
            if line[2] == '0' or line[2] == '1' or line[2] == 'None':
                if line[3] == 'R' or line[3] == 'L':
                    if line[4] == '0' or line[4] == '1':
                        if len(line) == 5:
                            return True
                        else:
                            return False
                    else:
                        return False
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: it would be much easier if you just tell us what the function is trying to achieve.

Comment: In general, *return early!* Do `if not …: return False` instead of many nested `if..else`.

Comment: In the first, second and third place should be 0 or 1, in the fourth place R or L, and in the fifth place 0 or 1

Comment: Create some maps, they usually help :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write it as something like:

```
def checkCardCommands(line):
    return (len(line) == 5
      and line[0] in ['0', '1']
      and line[1] in ['0', '1', 'None']
      and line[2] in ['0', '1', 'None']
      and line[3] in ['R', 'L']
      and line[4] in ['0', '1'])
```

Comment: i was actually fishing for some "inside" info on the use of `all()` vs. multiple `and` in boolean tupples. Sorry if it came out douchey

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: No worries. At least one of the other answers here uses `all()` effectively, though once you do that it starts to look somewhat [like this classic joke](http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/The_Evolution_of_a_Programmer.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
def check(line):
    spec = [
        ['0', '1'],
        ['0', '1', 'None'],
        ['0', '1', 'None'],
        ['R', 'L'],
        ['0', '1']
    ]

    return len(line) == len(spec) and all(ln in spc for ln, spc in zip(line, spec))
```

Shorter, and way more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

If your validations are not too complicated you could write some validation helpers yourself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

def validate(schema, seq):
    """
    Validates a given iterable against a schema. Schema is a list
    of callables, taking a single argument returning `True` if the
    passed value is valid, `False` otherwise.
    """
    if not len(schema) == len(seq):
        raise ValueError('length mismatch')
    for f, item in zip(schema, seq):
        if not f(item):
            raise ValueError('validation failed: %s' % (item))
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # two validation helper, add more here
    isbool = lambda s: s == '0' or s == '1'
    islr = lambda s: s == 'L' or s == 'R'

    # define a schema
    schema = [isbool, isbool, isbool, islr, isbool]
    # example input
    line = ['0', '1', '0', 'R', '1']

    # this is valid
    validate(schema, ['0', '1', '0', 'R', '1'])

    # ValueError: validation failed: X
    validate(schema, ['0', '1', '0', 'R', 'X'])

    # ValueError: length mismatch
    validate(schema, ['0', '1'])
```

For more advanced data structure schema validations, have a look at [voluptuous](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous).

> Voluptuous, despite the name, is a Python data validation library. It is primarily intended for validating data coming into Python as JSON, YAML, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkcards():
    return line[0] in ['0','1'] and line[1] in ['0','1','None'] and line[2] in ['0','1','None'] and line[3] in ['R','L'] and line[4] in ['0','1'] and len(line)==5
```

'None' is a string, None is an object type. make sure you know which one you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help in case of dynamic list to be checked.

```
line = ['0', '1', '0', 'R', '1']
check_list = [
    ['0', '1'],
    ['0', '1', 'None'],
    ['0', '1', 'None'],
    ['R', 'L'],
    ['0', '1']
]

def check():
  for l, item in enumerate(line):
    if not item in check_list[l]:
        return False
    elif l == 4:
        ### comes here only if each item in line is found in the check_list
        return True
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.